# How to change resource in an apk and rebuild the application

Tags: android, apk, rebuild

I lost the source code of my application due to system crash. Now I want to make a small change in an array resource and rebuild the application. Is there any way to change it directly in .apk??

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can, you need the source code and recompile the code and generate the apk.

Comment: isn't there any way to update resource using apktool or any such tool and rebuild application?

Comment: Before this problem, you should always have a backup copy of the code or simply a GIT repository.

I doubt that these tools allow you to recompile the project without the signatures and without the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Decompile the code from apk for this. If your apk was not protected by proguard or Dex etc. then you can get the code.

[Try this to get code from apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Then make changes in code and rebuild your apk.